# Simple Javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript and I feel like I have a decent grasp on the fundamentals but I am having problems making it do things that i want .. for example.. I am trying to create a simple form in html that calculates the sum of 2 numbers.. here is my html and javascript:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function adder(a,b) {
            var a = document.getElementById('firstNum').value;
            var b = document.getElementById('secondNum').value;
            var numbers = new Array(a,b);
            var sum = 0;

            for (i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
            }

            //this part i need help with
            document.getElementById('answer').write("First Number: " + a + " plus Second Number: " + b + " is " + sum).value; //this part i need help with
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="additionForm">
        A + B = C : <input type="text" id="firstNum" placeholder="A"> 
        + <input type="text" id="secondNum" placeholder="B">
        <input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add" onClick="adder();">
        = <input type="text" id="answer" placeholder="C">
    </form>
</body>
```

My problem is that i don't know how to get the javascript to overwrite the value attribute for my form input id=answer .. or if i'm supposed to be using Jquery instead .. thanks in advance.

Comment: `"or if i'm supposed to be using Jquery instead"` Please don't forget this: there is **nothing** that jQuery *can* do and plain JavaScript *cannot*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function adder() {
  var a = parseInt( document.getElementById('firstNum').value, 10);
   var b = parseInt( document.getElementById('secondNum').value, 10);
   var sum = a + b;

  //this part i need help with
  document.getElementById('answer').value = "First Number: " + a + " plus Second Number: " + b + " is " + sum).value; //this part i need help with
}
```

Comment: ahh parseInt .. i've never seen that before but i learned a bit of python before and i remember that basically any input from the user is a string .. so you must change the input into a number before you can just simply say var sum = a + b; otherwise you are just joining strings.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify an input field in javascript, you can simply set the `value` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('answer').value = "First Number: " + a + " plus Second Number: " + b + " is " + sum;
```